# Log revisions of svn checked out modules into one file or several files

Tags: performance, file, memory, logging

I need to keep track of revisions of several subversion modules I check out daily and for this I want to log them into a file and later use this logged info to check them out again. Is it better to keep them all in one file or each file per day? By better I mean performance/memory impacts.

The number of modules I have is around 10.

I keep just the revision numbers, e.g. 8912, 7841, ... 9312 and a tag (build_number) binding them together, like a dictionary in python: {build_number: revisions_list}.

The burden of this job is opening the file and reading it, finding the tag matching my query and returning the list. I am not sure if it makes sense to have a large number of small files or one big file.

Comment: could you provide som details on your modules?

Comment: How is that relevant? I just need the revisions of modules logged!

Comment: I was thinking that the number of modules would have an impact on performance?

Comment: How much info would it be in the logs? Meomorywise? How Heavy is the computational burden of using them? How would you use them? Is it the performance load when logging or when using you are worried about?

Comment: Just revision numbers, e.g. 8912, 7841, ... 9312 and a tag (build_number) connecting them together, like a dictionary in python: {build_number: revisions_list}. The burden is opening the file and reading it, finding the tag matching my query and returning the list.

Comment: If you edit your original question adding these specification I you should improve your chances of getting a good reply!

Comment: Thanks for the helps @Mats